# Java Spring Boot web app run well on local but get Whitelabel Error Page when deployed to azure web app service

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, maven, jsp

I have a simple spring boot web app using jsp files and maven like this

[image: My jsp view files in 'webapp/views' folder]

And my **pom.xml** not show above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <parent> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>2.4.1</version>  
    <relativePath/>  
    <!-- lookup parent from repository --> 
  </parent>  
  <groupId>com.sat</groupId>  
  <artifactId>satellite</artifactId>  
  <version>6.0.0</version>  
  <name>satellite</name>
  <description>Satellite Official Website</description>  
  <properties> 
    <java.version>1.8</java.version> 
  </properties>  
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Embed Tomcat-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>  
      <version>1.2</version> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- JSP Parse -->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>  
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- Spring Web -->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- MySQL -->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>  
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>  
      <scope>runtime</scope> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- LomBok -->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>  
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>  
      <optional>true</optional> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- Live Dev Tools -->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>  
      <optional>true</optional> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>  
      <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>  
    <!--Others-->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>  
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>  
      <version>3.11</version> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>  
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>  
      <version>20201115</version> 
    </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
  <build> 
    <plugins> 
      <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
        <configuration> 
          <excludes> 
            <exclude> 
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>  
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId> 
            </exclude> 
          </excludes> 
        </configuration> 
      </plugin>
    </plugins> 
  </build> 
</project>
```

It run normal on my local computer, i used inteliji and run with '**SatelliteApplication**' mainclass
Then I using Azure Tool for Inteliji to deploy it to azure web app service, i done it as below:

[image]

The console tell that i have deploy this web app successfully to azure, but when I go to my websites, it have this error, can anyone help me to fix this?
[image]

Comment: For starters stop mixing module from different versions. Your tomcat is including 2.3.1, remove the version tag.

Comment: i removed it but still get this error